# How Spark achieves memory fairness between tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, memory-management

I was watching this [presentation](https://databricks.com/session/deep-dive-apache-spark-memory-management) that is about spark memory management.

He talks about how they achieve fairness between different tasks in one executor (12:00). And he presents the idea of dynamic assignment between tasks and he declares that Spark spill other task's pages to disk if more tasks begin to execute.

I read before tasks in Spark are essentially threads and in Java we don't have this capability to manage the memory of threads and establish memory fairness between them. I wonder how Spark achievs this?

Comment: You must have missed an intro where presenter would say that Spark _manages_ `spark.memory.fraction` portion of Java heap. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview

Comment: thank you but how actually this explain how spark establish memory fairness between tasks? how it tracks how much memory each task used?

Comment: there is no fairness, you get resources

Comment: @thebluephantom  can you explain more this please? when presenter explains the idea of  dynamic assignment he literally says that each task is assigned 1/N of the memory if we have N tasks, and if new task comes along we have to spill some memory blocks allocated to currently running tasks to disk to make room for this new task. it is fairness I think

Comment: but even with dynamic you get allocated

Comment: @thebluephantom my question is how spark achieved this? equally and dynamically distributes resources between threads/tasks?

Comment: I am interested to see what is better than that excellent article.

Comment: @thebluephantom that is ok and I am grateful for that and the time you put into this question, but I couldn't come to conclusion what is going on under the hood and what is correct. I see some people say spark manages tasks and doesn't allow one task take most of the memory and some people don't agree. for example take a look at this https://luminousmen.com/post/dive-into-spark-memory/ author claims `TaskMemoryManager` limits memory allocation for tasks.

Comment: and if you see the source code of `TaskMemoryManager` you see sometimes it spills. I want only one big picture how these components stick together

Comment: Well, you can upvote then. But I have to say this knowledge is at a low level and hard for you to exploit in practice. In general things work well. I will be watching this space.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about fairness being valid.

- Here is an excellent read on executor memory divided over more than 1 core per Executor https://www.davidmcginnis.net/post/spark-job-optimization-myth-5-increasing-executor-cores-is-always-a-good-idea, which has nothing to do with spilling to disk.
- Spilling to disk is if too large for available memory. Also a partition can be completely evicted, resulting in re-computation (from last checkpoint).

Where I have been the paradigm was similar to this article in that we ran more Executors with a single Core. The default from Spark is indeed 1 as well, I would assume that that was a thought out default from the vendor.